# MySQL Tricky Where Clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have a mysql table that contains a column called sequence.

Here is my statment:

```
SELECT
a.modelyear,
count(*) as yearcount
FROM styles a, jpgs b, models c, divisions d
WHERE d.divisionid = c.divisionid
AND a.styleid = b.styleid
AND c.modelid = a.modelid
AND a.mktclassid in ($this->mktclassids)
AND a.sequence = 0
$this->where
GROUP BY a.modelyear;
```

the above query should output counts equal to this query:

```
select count(distinct(modelid)) from styles where mktclassid in ($this->mktclassids)
$this->where
```

My problem is that in order to get every unique modelid for the count. sequence can equal 0 or 1, but not both.
So a modelid might have a sequence = 0. If it doesnt equal 0 then it will equal 1.
I need like an if statment in my where clause.

This is what i think i need:

```
if modelid has a.sequence = 0, then use a.sequence = 0
else modelid does not have a.sequence = 0, then use a.sequence = 1
```

I am not a mysql guy so sorry if i am not expressing what i need..
Basically if the modelid does not have a sequence = 0 then it will have sequence = 1

The styles table has many trim levels for each model. And the first trim will either equal 0 or 1. this is an example of the styles table

```
styleid modelid sequence
350422  25156   1
350425  25156   4
350426  25156   5
350427  25156   7
350428  25156   11
350429  25156   6
350432  25156   9
350433  25156   10
356717  25156   8

styleid modelid sequence
308367  18875   0
308368  18875   1
308369  18875   2
308370  18875   3
308371  18875   4
```

I am trying to get a distinst modelid from this table.
I do not believe that i can use DISTINCT though because it will effect my entire query.

so you can see that this model does not have a sequence = 0, so i would need to use sequence = 1
maybe a contains 1 OR 0...I am not sure
any help is greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question. You say that sequence is either 0 or 1, but your example of the styles table shows lots of sequences that are not 0 or 1, and none of them are 0.

Comment: Could you post a more complete example of the input tables, and the output you're hoping to get from it? Maybe make a sqlfiddle.

Comment: The OP has no idea what he actually wants. See my answer below and all comments on it. The OP needs to clarify what it is that he needs and should do so with an http://sqlfiddle.com/ of example database and example output that is trying to be reached and what it is that is not giving the correct output. the sequence has no effect for what the OP stated that he needed last in comments....

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
...
AND (a.sequence=0 OR a.sequence=1)
...
```

I would do joins instead of using all those WHERE statements as well to optimize this query.

```
SELECT
    a.modelyear,
    count(*) as yearcount
FROM
    styles a
    INNER JOIN jpgs b ON (a.styleid = b.styleid)
    INNER JOIN models c ON (c.modelid = a.modelid)
    INNER JOIN divisions d ON (d.divisionid = c.divisionid)
WHERE
    a.mktclassid in ($this->mktclassids)
    AND (a.sequence=0 OR a.sequence=1)
    $this->where
GROUP BY 
    a.modelyear;
```

The above query will get all items that are sequences 1 OR 0 this next query took me some thinking. I will explain with query comments `#`, but it should get items that do not have both a sequence of 1 and 0:

```
SELECT
    a.modelyear,
    count(*) as yearcount
FROM
    styles a
    INNER JOIN jpgs b ON (a.styleid = b.styleid)
    INNER JOIN models c ON (c.modelid = a.modelid)
    INNER JOIN divisions d ON (d.divisionid = c.divisionid)
WHERE
    a.mktclassid in ($this->mktclassids)
    #above same as previous
    #and where modelid is in modelids either having sequence 0 or 1 but not both:
    AND a.modelid IN (
        #SELECT modelids that have either sequence 0 or 1 but not both
        SELECT
            styles.modelid
        FROM
            styles
        WHERE
            (
                styles.modelid IN (#modelids having sequence 0 but not 1
                    SELECT
                        styles.modelid
                    FROM
                        styles
                    WHERE
                        styles.sequence=0
                    GROUP BY
                        styles.modelid
                ) AND 
                styles.modelid  NOT IN (
                    SELECT
                        styles.modelid
                    FROM
                        styles
                    WHERE
                        styles.sequence=1
                    GROUP BY
                        styles.modelid
                ) 
            )
            OR
            (
                styles.modelid NOT IN (#modelids having sequence 1 but not 0
                    SELECT
                        styles.modelid
                    FROM
                        styles
                    WHERE
                        styles.sequence=0
                    GROUP BY
                        styles.modelid
                ) AND 
                styles.modelid IN (
                    SELECT
                        styles.modelid
                    FROM
                        styles
                    WHERE
                        styles.sequence=1
                    GROUP BY
                        styles.modelid
                ) 
            )
    )
    $this->where
GROUP BY 
    a.modelyear
```

I hope this is not too confusing

User states the query runs forever. Try just this subquery part and let me know about its performance.

```
        SELECT
            styles.modelid
        FROM
            styles
        WHERE
            (
                styles.modelid IN (
                    SELECT
                        styles.modelid
                    FROM
                        styles
                    WHERE
                        styles.sequence=0
                    GROUP BY
                        styles.modelid
                ) AND 
                styles.modelid  NOT IN (
                    SELECT
                        styles.modelid
                    FROM
                        styles
                    WHERE
                        styles.sequence=1
                    GROUP BY
                        styles.modelid
                ) 
            )
            OR
            (
                styles.modelid NOT IN (
                    SELECT
                        styles.modelid
                    FROM
                        styles
                    WHERE
                        styles.sequence=0
                    GROUP BY
                        styles.modelid
                ) AND 
                styles.modelid IN (
                    SELECT
                        styles.modelid
                    FROM
                        styles
                    WHERE
                        styles.sequence=1
                    GROUP BY
                        styles.modelid
                ) 
            )
```

> so i am just looking to get the distinct modelids from the table, but it is prefered that the sequence be 0 or 1 - OP

```
SELECT
    modelid,
    sequence
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            modelid,
            sequence
        FROM
            styles
        ORDER BY
            sequence ASC
    ) AS sub_query
GROUP BY
    modelid
```

> thats exactly what i need. How would i add that as a where clause to my original query? - OP

```
SELECT
a.modelyear,
count(*) as yearcount
FROM styles a, jpgs b, models c, divisions d
WHERE d.divisionid = c.divisionid
AND a.styleid = b.styleid
AND c.modelid = a.modelid
AND a.mktclassid in ($this->mktclassids)
AND a.modelid IN (
    SELECT
        modelid
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                modelid,
                sequence
            FROM
                styles
            ORDER BY
                sequence ASC
        ) AS sub_query
    GROUP BY
        modelid
)
$this->where
GROUP BY a.modelyear;
```

Which would result to the same as:

```
SELECT
a.modelyear,
count(*) as yearcount
FROM styles a, jpgs b, models c, divisions d
WHERE d.divisionid = c.divisionid
AND a.styleid = b.styleid
AND c.modelid = a.modelid
AND a.mktclassid in ($this->mktclassids)
AND a.modelid IN (
    SELECT
        modelid
    FROM
        styles
    GROUP BY
        modelid
)
$this->where
GROUP BY a.modelyear;
```

**I do not think that this is what you acutally want though. You do not need this as a WHERE clause but you need to have a completely better Query altogether. Are the other tables necessary? What does** `$this->where` **equate to?**

After thinking over this for another hour, I think this might be what you actually want. This limits the styles table to only one modelid and sorts them to the lowest sequence and then it joins on the other tables and applies the mktclassid IN clause and the `$this->where` clause:

```
SELECT
a.modelyear,
count(*) as yearcount
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            (
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                styles
            ORDER BY
                sequence ASC
            ) subquery
        GROUP BY
            modelid
    ) a
    INNER JOIN jpgs b ON (a.styleid = b.styleid)
    INNER JOIN models c ON (c.modelid = a.modelid)
    INNER JOIN divisions d ON (d.divisionid = c.divisionid)
WHERE 
    a.mktclassid in ($this->mktclassids) AND
    $this->where
GROUP BY a.modelyear;
```

After this, I am done and have no more advice to give other than **CLARIFY** your question and **PLEASE** provide an [sqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) and give more examples of expected output. Sometimes the problem you are facing is because what you are trying to do is going about things the wrong way. If possible always give the reason to why you are doing something other than just the here's my problem... Others may be able to simplify the process and provide a solution that solves the real problem. Good luck!

Comment: that doesnt work because the majority of the trims have a sequence = 1 and a sequence = 0. There are about 50 that do not have a sequence = 0, but a sequence = 1..basically if it has a sequence = 0 then it has a sequence = 1, but not vice-versa.

Comment: @user2506624 you are going to have to provide more details with some of the other tables then. How can you have one row that is both sequence 0 and sequence 1. Sounds like you need a subquery

Comment: I edited my original post to hopefully clarify what i am looking for

Comment: @user2506624 please see edited answer, hope it is not too confusing.

Comment: I tried it and couldnt get it to run, sequelpro is complaining about the f,g,h,i,e. But taking those out the query just runs forever. The results are displayed to users so speed is very important. modelyear is incorrect did u mean sequence?

Comment: @user2506624 sorry, I had my syntax wrong and was using the wrong column names... try edited answer again

Comment: @user2506624 did the updated query work for you?

Comment: it looks to be the correct syntax, but sequelpro just hangs and the query processes for like 10+ minutes..there is no easier way to do this. i just need something like a DISTINCT clause

Comment: @user2506624 try to run the last edited subquery and let me know about performance. Also, how many unique modelid do you think you have. and how many total?

Comment: running this query: select count(distinct(modelid)) from styles = 1664 unique modelids. that subquery runs forever too, but its hard to tell if its just sequelpro.I mean essentially all i need is a way to include distinct(modelid) into my original query without messing the rest of it up, which i do not believe is possible

Comment: do you have proper indexing on modelid?

Comment: I don't think that distinct(modelid) would work even if you could include it in your original query because then how would you know if the sequence is 1 or 0 but not both?

Comment: i do have an index on modelid in the styles table. I think i have been explaining this wrong. I do not need to know whether sequence is 1 or 0, i just need the distinct modelids, i was uing sequence = 0 because i thought it was distinct but not every modelid has a sequence = 0..so i am just looking to get the distinct modelids from the table, but it is prefered that the sequence be 0 or 1, because these are the most common trim levels..I Hope this clears up some confusion. And thank you very much for working through this with me. Can I grab the first sequence of each modelid somehow?

Comment: @user2506624 to get the distinct modelids from the table with preferred sequence 0 or 1 run the above last edited query.

Comment: thats exactly what i need. How would i add that as a where clause to my original query?

Comment: @user2506624 well, It is there however, i do not think it is what you need. It does pretty much nothing. Please give more data as to what results you are expecting and what you are `trim levels` and reword your original question before I will be able to be of any more assistance.

Comment: @user2506624 Ok, I am done. I cannot spend any more time on this one question. Please see last and final edited answer with what I think you might actually need.